# How to go to the launcher where all the apps are listed?

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher, android-launcher

There is a button in my app, when user clicks it, she will be leaded to the launcher interface.

I tried the following way:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(startMain);
```

But it goes to the "Home screen"(on the left), rather the "Launcher screen"(on the right).

I also tried `Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`, but it pops up a dialog for selecting an app to finish the action.

[image]

Comment: The screen on the left **is**  the launcher.  The one on the right is the app drawer.  It is a custom view, specific to the launcher, and is not exposed in the manifest.  Therefore, it cannot be started from another app.

Comment: To be precise, it's possible for a given launcher to advertise an intent filter to open the app drawer but that's launcher specific and not part of the stock Android launchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to go to the launcher where all the apps are listed?

You don't, unless perhaps you are the author of the home screen in question.

As Simon indicates, there is no requirement for any home screen to allow external apps to directly go to a separate "launcher". Not every home screen even *has* a separate "launcher" (some blend the app widgets and launcher icons in a single display).

You are welcome to contact the authors of various home screen implementations and see if they expose some special `Intent` structure that would take you to the launcher.